# How to get the domain name for a Sitecore item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a multi site Sitecore installation.  I am trying to create an email that gets sent out that contains links back to the Sitecore editor for each item.  I have it all working except the correct domain name.  Given an item ID how would I use the API to get the domain for that item?  For example - I want to produce a URL like the following:

http://www.mySite1.com/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?id=id

The only part I'm not sure about is how to programmatically retrieve the "www.mySite1.com" part.  Any ideas?  I can never find stuff like this in the Sitecore API although I am sure it is there somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure that that functionality is in there... at least not in the earlier version of Sitecore 6. Sitecore is more or less built to be a single domain solution, though you can overcome most of the problems with it. But this problem usually requires some custom code to give you the correct domain.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you have multiple sites set up in the `<sites>` section of your web.config file and that each one has a `hostName` property defined e.g.

```
<site name="website1" hostName="website1.com" ...
<site name="website2" hostName="website2.com" ...
```

You can use the SiteManager class to access info about each sites including the hostName

```
Sitecore.Sites.SiteManager.GetSite("website1").Properties["hostName"]
```

.. if you are running in a Sitecore page you can access the currently running `Site` object using

```
Sitecore.Context.Site
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

I think there are a few approaches for you:

1. In your `<linkManager>` config, set `alwaysIncludeServerUrl` to `true` so calls to `GetItemUrl()` have absolute full URLs.
2. Set the barely documented `targetHostName` attribute on the `<site ... />` node in your `web.config` and ensure the Sitecore config setting `Rendering.SiteResolving` is set to `true`. This should then resolve the correct target hostname given the site in context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will work in a multi site environment but you could call `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl`. If this wont work you can get the hostname by calling `Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName`, `Sitecore.Context.Site.TargetHostName` or `Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["hostName"]` if you access it via a page as previously mentioned.

Comment: I have multi domains that one for sitecore, one for other third party app. They share the same sitecore content for navigation banner. When navigate to the third party app, I need to use `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` to get back to 'HOME' url which is the main sitecore  domain.